# javascript: check if variable is a specific letter

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

Very basic javascript, i'm a complete beginner trying to construct an if statement to check if a variable is a specific letter

more specifically, if a user input for a variable is "P", "M" or "G"

i'm using

```
if (variable = P) {

statement   
        }
```

but doesn't seem to be working

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use quotes around P for string comparison.

Comment: Worked, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

In addition to forgetting the quotes around the letter `"P"`, you've used the assignment operator `=`, instead of the comparator `==`.

Check this out:

```
var name = "Carolyn";
console.log(name);
# "Carolyn"

var name_is_carolyn = (name == "Carolyn");
console.log(name_is_carolyn);
# true
```

Changing your code to this should help:

```
if (variable == "P") {
  // statement   
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Carolyn!

Comment: you are absolutely right Carolyn, but i think simplyfied if case is perhaps too much for a beginner who does not know about the difference on =, ==, and === or how to write string ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(variable == 'P' || variable == 'G' || variable == 'M') {
  // do something
}
```

take care, it's case sensitive without using toLowerCase or toUpperCase on the string.

anther way is:

```
switch(variable.toLowerCase()) {
  case 'p':
    // do something for p
    break;
  case 'm':
  case 'g':
    // do something for m and g (no break; in m case)
    break;
  default:
    // no match, so do something else
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you can do it in JS:

```
TextLetter=function(txt,letter){
try{
var TXT=txt.split(letter);
if(TXT.length>0)
return true;
else
return false;
}catch(err){
return false;
}
}
TextLetter(prompt("Type in text","TEXT"),prompt("Look for the character or phrase...","?"));
```

I didn't test this yet, but should be helpful